# How can i use a base 64 string as a normal map?

Tags: three.js, base64

the title explains it pretty much. I have a normal map encoded in base 64 and I want to use it on a model. I have been trying some examples that I found online but to no avail.

```
var curObj = mesh.getObjectByName(object + "_low")
var image = new Image()
var texture = new THREE.Texture(image)
image.src = reader.result
curObj.material.normalMap = image
image.onload = function() { texture.needsUpdate = true }
```

Object is a string that is the name of the part that I want to apply the normal map to. The base 64 string is reader.result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option, try this approach:

```js
var curObj = mesh.getObjectByName(object + "_low");
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(reader.result);
curObj.material.normalMap = texture;
curObj.material.needsUpdate = true; // just in case, if the material didn't have `normalMap` before
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to assign the `texture` as a normalMap, not the `image`. Additionally, I would create the texture after the image has finished loading, not before:

```js
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
    var curObj = mesh.getObjectByName(object + "_low");
    var texture = new THREE.Texture(image);
    curObj.material.normalMap = texture; // Make sure this is the texture.
}

// I believe .src needs to be assigned after .onload has been declared
image.src = reader.result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunatley it still wont work, just as an extra percaution I checked if the base 64 string was correct and it was so I have still no clue what is going on.

Comment: Hmm…  what exactly doesn’t work? Does the desired image display if you assign it to an `<img>` element in the DOM?